# How to host GitHub repository on an organization without losing my name?

Tags: github

Is it possible to have a github project/repository be under my name and also have it part of an organization? For example, hosting my project under an organization would give it the name https://github.com/ORGANIZATION-XYZ whereeas hosting it on my own profile would give it the name https://github.com/Kong

What can I do? Fork?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the "Kong" account to an organization if your primary worry is the name. However, there are some caveats:

```
Warning: Before converting a user into an organization, keep these points in mind:

    You will no longer be able to sign into the converted user account.
    You will no longer be able to create or modify gists owned by the converted user account.
    An organization cannot be converted back to a user.
    The SSH keys, OAuth tokens, job profile, reactions, and associated user information, will not be transferred to the organization. This is only true for the user account that's being converted, not any of the user account's collaborators.
    Any commits made with the converted user account will no longer be linked to that account. The commits themselves will remain intact.
```

This can be done under "Settings" -> "Organization" -> "Transform account" as described in https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/converting-a-user-into-an-organization

Comment: I think there are none.